# Gantt getting screen reader to read completed value as a percentage

Tags: highcharts

I'm defining a valueDescriptionFormat with:"{point.name} from {point.x:%Y-%m-%d} to {point.x2:%Y-%m-%d}, completed {point.completed} percent" and it is not reading the percentage, just the word completed. What is the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `{point.completed.amount}`:

**Example config:**

```
  accessibility: {
    point: {
      valueDescriptionFormat: "{point.name} from {point.x:%Y-%m-%d} to {point.x2:%Y-%m-%d}, completed {(multiply point.completed.amount 100)}%"
    }
  },
```

**Demo:**
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/e0q4yw9a/

Comment: Just a note that the computation is only available in 11.1, but still the right answer.